# Laravel 5.7, How to decrypt or view Hash Password in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I stored my password Hash method in laravel 5.7

```
'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
```

I need to view original password so can you help any one?

Comment: Hashing is an one-way action. In theory you cannot reverse-engineer to view the password. However, through techniques like Rainbow Table, you may have a slight chance to lookup the password.

Comment: Can not do that, you can only check if the password matches. Why do you need to see the password?

Comment: @SudhansuBhatta I need to send password to user when the admin confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot decrypt hashed passwords. You can only attempt brute force checking.

You can check if a password matches the hash by using

```
Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword);
```

This function will return true if the passwords match, else false. You can get more info about hashing from [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing)

There should never be a case of needing to view your password, because that would be a big flaw. A lot of users use same password on multiple sites so being able to view password will be a huge security risk. If someone gains unauthorised access to your database, then just imagine if they could see passwords, accounts on multiple sites could get could get compromised if same password is used.

If you forget password, then reset it. No harm done.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, once Password is hash and cannot be seen, it only check if the given password is right or wrong using Hash Check

```
$user=User::find(Auth::user()->id);

if(Hash::check('secret', $user->password)){
  //if it is true, the condition is passed
 }
```

you Have to import ***User, Auth, Hash*** in controller.